# Hosting multiple instance of app in a tabcontrol/ queuing

Tags: c#, multithreading, ui-thread

So I have This app with a MainForm that has a few buttons on it. and the buttons would do time consuming tasks that includes working with MainForm UI. Because some times we need to run multiple instances of this app at the sametime I decided to Create a MainFormHost where it is a form with a tab control which under each tab I create an instance of my MainForm and host it there. And so far everything was ok. The problem is when I click on a button on MAinForm1 it starts working fine but as soon as I click on a button on MainForm2 the process of MainForm1 button gets queued behind the MainForm2 process.

```
MainForm GetMainFrom(TabPage tabPage)
{
tabPage.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    mainForm = new MainForm();
    mainForm.TopLevel = false;
    mainForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    mainForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    _mainForms.Add(mainForm);
    tabPage.Controls.Add(mainForm);
    mainForm.Show();

}));
}
```

And then call the method:

```
var mainFormThread = new Thread(() =>
{
    mainForm = GetMainFrom(tabPage);
});

mainFormThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
mainFormThread.Start();
```

I cannot change the code inside the MainForm to Invoke things when they want to work with the UI because it is going to be too much of work but I can easily make each button click to be called from a thread/task or...

TIA

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can only have one 'main thread' that can interact with the UI controls. Ever. Period. There is no way to get around this (in standard code, you can draw to your form from a different process, but I won't go into that)

So, what you need to do is arrange your code in a set pattern.

- Methods that do background work - this can be done on a separate thread(s)
- Methods that Update the UI - MUST be done on the UI/Main Thread

The idea being simple, background work takes a long time, and updating the UI shouldn't.

Because you have 1 or 2 long running actions running ON THE MAIN UI THREAD, this 'blocks the UI' and causes the behavior your are experiencing.

By blocks the UI, what you actually have is the Windows Message pump can't pump. So every single command to resize a window or update a control on a form is a message in the pump. That must run on the main thread. If you do 'work' on that thread, such as connecting to a database, download a file etc., then the pump can't continue, so you get the 'this application is not responding' message.

So, you must download the file or whatever on a thread, and when it's finished, transition to the UI thread, and update the UI, e.g. say finished in a text box.

The way to transition between the two threads (background to main) is to use begininvoke, and you know if this is needed by using 'invoke required' .

From MSDN

```html
// This method demonstrates a pattern for making thread-safe
// calls on a Windows Forms control. 
//
// If the calling thread is different from the thread that
// created the TextBox control, this method creates a
// SetTextCallback and calls itself asynchronously using the
// Invoke method.
//
// If the calling thread is the same as the thread that created
// the TextBox control, the Text property is set directly. 

private void SetText(string text)
{
 // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
 // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
 // If these threads are different, it returns true.
 if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
 { 
  SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
  this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
 }
 else
 {
  this.textBox1.Text = text;
 }
}
```

This is a great article and will get you where you need to be:
[MSDN about thread safe code and invoke required](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. However I kinda did know most of what you explained but my question was if there is a way/shortcut for me not to go through making these kind of changes to my code. e.g looking for something like creating multiple UI threads or how ever it works when I run two instances of my app and they work fine without blocking each other. I jsut dont want to have a lot of windows open and prefer to have the instances being managed under a tab control.

Comment: Apart from multiple processes (basically multiple copies of your application running) then no, there is not. You have a fundamental design problem sorry. The simplest way to 'correct it' would be to use the Task Framework.